# Using find to delete in multiple directories with one command

Tags: shell-script

I wanted to list out all the subfolder under the path `${BASE_PATH}/*/${env}/{state1,state2,state3,state4}/*_BNDL/{log,state}` (under this datetime stamp folder will be present) and wanted to delete automated way.

```
BASE_PATH=/data/jobs/runs
env=test
find ${BASE_PATH}/*/${env}/{state1,state2,state3,state4}/*_BNDL/{log,state} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -ctime +15
```

But on PyCharm I am getting this warning

In POSIX sh, brace expansion is undefined. See SC2039, I am able to run the command on the shell and it works fine but why this warning?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let your IDE know which shell is going to be used to run your code. The best way to do this is to add the appropriate shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash
BASE_PATH=/data/jobs/runs
env=test
find "${BASE_PATH}"/*/"${env}"/{state1,state2,state3,state4}/*_BNDL/{log,state} -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -ctime +15
```

You can also use [a `shell` directive instead](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/Directive#shell), but this isn’t appropriate here.

Comment: Or zsh instead of bash, and then you can do `print -rC1 -- $BASE_PATH/*/$env/state<1-4>/*_BNDL/{log,state}/*(ND/c+15)` with a few advantages: (1) doesn't fail i `$BASE_PATH` with `-`, (2) not affected by the `execve()` limit on the size of arguments, (3) gives a sorted list (4) is shorter, (5) removes the need for a `find` supporting those non standard `-mindepth`/`-maxdepth` predicates.

Comment: (clarification on my command above: `<1-4>` matches any decimal integer number between 1 and 4, including 1, 00002, and 4. Use `[1-4]` or `[1234]` to match any single digits from 1 to 4 or you could use `state{1..4}` (from zsh) or `{state1,state2,state3,state4}` (from csh) though that's not a globbing operator).